# call back function get called multiple times on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I have list of items with a delete item button at the end of each list. Now when user clicks on delete button a bootstrap modal pops up to confirm if user wanted to delete the item 
here is the code for it

```
function showConfirmationPopup(title, message, onConfirmationCallback,params) {
    var confirmationtPopup = $("#confirmationPopup");
    confirmationtPopup.find(".modal-body").text(message);

    $("#confirmationPopupOKBtn").on("click", function (e) {
        confirmationtPopup.modal("hide");
        onConfirmationCallback(params);
    })

    confirmationtPopup.modal("show");
}
```

When user confirm and press the OK button on pop up it calls the call back function.

Now when I delete an item 1st time from the list it works fine when I delete 2nd time it goes to the OK button action listener two times.

For example if I delete item with id 1 and it call the OK action listener and work fine.When I delete item with id 2 it calls the call back function with ID 1 and 2.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Cheers!!

Comment: You're creating a new on click event handler inside your method every time.  That's your issue.

Comment: How can I overcome this issue?I want old event listener to be void when the dialogue box is closed.